# SQL Server convert date to MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS as DATETIME format

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am looking to convert the SQL Server date format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:MS) to US format (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS) but the data type should remain datetime.

Further details. Apologies as this may help. I have a 3rd party application which uses a view in SQL Server 2008. However, this app will only allow me to filter dates if the data type is date or datetime which is why using convert and varchar does not work in this case.

Comment: Dates in SQL Server don't have a format, what are you doing with the date? You just need to format the display in your user interface.

Answer (score 2):

How SQL Server stores dates has nothing to do with how they are formatted to users. You can format dates almost anyway you want to when presenting the data to users. How the date is actually stored in the DB is not affected by this.

For information on how to present dates to users, take a look at the following T-SQL functions:

```
Convert
Cast
Format (SQL 2012)
```

As an example:

```
Print FORMAT(GetDate(),'G','en-us')
```

will produce:

```
9/3/2014 8:15:49 AM
```

But the underlying data type isn't changed.

Comment: While this is accurate and useful information, I dislike having it as an answer.

Comment: Isn't FORMAT a SQL Server 2012 only function? I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: You didn't specify the version in your post. If you are using 2012, look at Convert and/or Cast.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, the way a date is displayed and how it is stored are two different things. However, this code will get you the display you asked for, in transact sql.

```
declare @d    [datetime] = N'2014-09-03 07:24:16:23'
    , @s      [sysname]
    , @target [sysname];
set @s = convert ([sysname], @d, 113);
set @target = convert ([sysname], @d, 101) + N' '
          + substring(@s, charindex(N':', @s, 7) - 2, 8);
select @target, convert([datetime], @target);
```